# Append StringSegment to StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, stringbuilder, implicit-conversion

I have a [`StringSegment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringsegment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2) and need to append it to a `StringBuilder` instance. Want to use the [`StringBuilder.Append(StringSegment)` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.extensions.append?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2) that is part of Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, but two overloads that are actual instance methods of `StringBuilder` take precedence.

The implicit conversion operators defined in `StringSegment` are to blame. They do not allow me to use the intended extension naturally and furthermore they make the call ambiguous between `StringBuilder.Append(ReadOnlyMemory<char>)` and `StringBuilder.Append(ReadOnlySpan<char>)`, requiring a cast to disambiguate.

I know I can just

```
using static Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.Extensions;

Append(stringBuilder, stringSegment);
```

but that reads unnaturally and thus somewhat defeats the purpose of extension methods. I can also inline the extension method and call the `StringBuilder.Append(string, int, int)` overload directly, but that feels even worse due to being chatty.

Is there a way to append the string segment that reads naturally and is concise?

Using .NET Core 3.1 and C# 8, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use an extension method of a different name that does not collide with the applicable instance methods. Either wrap the original extension method, or re-implement it as it is trivial.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

public static StringBuilder AppendSegment(this StringBuilder builder, StringSegment segment)
{
    return Extensions.Append(builder, segment);
}
```